# Signature of "__dict__" incompatible with supertype "object"

Tags: python, class

I don't now why gave me this error the code is the next:

```
import json

from typing import List


class RepeatedValue:
    def __init__(self, element: int, indexes: List[int]) -> None:
        self.element: int = element
        self.indexes: List[int] = indexes

    # Use __dict__ attribute instead of defining a custom __dict__ method
    def __dict__(self) -> dict:
        return {"element": self.element, "indexes": self.indexes}


class RepetitionEvaluator:

    def __init__(self, unique_values: List[dict],
              repeated_values: 
              List[RepeatedValue]) -> None:
        self.unique = unique_values
        self.repeated = repeated_values

class RepetitionEvaluatorPascualinda:
    def __init__(self):
        self.withness = {}
        self.unique_values: List[dict] = []
        self.repeated_values: List[RepeatedValue]

    def _process_with_withness(self, numbers: List[int]) -> None:
        self.withness.clear()
        for index, value in enumerate(numbers):
            if value in self.withness:
                self.withness[value].append(index)
                continue
            self.withness[value] = [index]
            print("Todos los numeros fueron procesados correctamente..")

    def _process_unique(self) -> List[dict]:
        return [{
          index[0]: value
        } for value, index in self.withness.items() if len(index) == 1]

    def _process_repeated(self) -> List[RepeatedValue]:
        return [
          RepeatedValue(value, index) for value, index in self.withness.items()
          if len(index) > 1
        ]

    def evaluate(self, numbers: List[int], json_output: bool = False):
        self._process_with_withness(numbers)
        self.unique_values = self._process_unique()
        self.repeated_values = self._process_repeated()
        output = RepetitionEvaluator(self.unique_values, self.repeated_values)
        if not json_output:
            return output
        # Use a custom encoder to handle serialization
        return json.dumps(output, indent=2, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)


def main() -> None:
    numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    evaluator = RepetitionEvaluatorPascualinda()
    print("object output:", evaluator.evaluate(numbers).repeated[0].__dict__)
    print("JSON output:", evaluator.evaluate(numbers, True))


if (__name__) == "__main__":
    main()
```

And then in the terminal used the library of mypy and  it says this:

> error: Signature of "`__dict__`" incompatible with supertype "`object`"  [override].

And now i want to now why it gives me this error and why the code it isn't work? If you could give me complete answers and examples I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Please fix the code indentation. The methods have to be indented inside the classes. And post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: There are indented, it's stack overflow that don't let me put it correctly

Comment: Why are you writing a `__dict__` method, right under a comment that says "Use `__dict__` attribute instead of defining a custom `__dict__` method"?

Comment: This looks like a known mypy bug: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6523

Comment: Hold on a moment, why are you defining a `__dict__` method to begin with??

Comment: I tried to serialize a Object without a library

Comment: @JoaquínRuiz that absolutely does not make sense. Why do you think you should *ever* define a `__dict__` method? is it because you did: `json.dumps(output, indent=2, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)`?

Comment: Why did a __dict__ it's incorrect?

Comment: @JoaquínRuiz it makes *no sense*. You haven't explained *why* you are doing it. And you seem to be fundamentally confused about how the `default` argument works. But note, your default serializer *would already work* without you having to define `__dict__`, since it *is already defined*.

Answer (score 0):

`__dict__` is a dict attribute of an `object` instance, not a method that takes `self` as an argument, which is why mypy complains about your definition of `__dict__` being incompatible with that of `object`.

To make it compatible you can make `__dict__` a property instead:

```
@property
def __dict__(self) -> dict:
    return {"element": self.element, "indexes": self.indexes}
```

But then mypy will complain that "Cannot override writeable attribute with read-only property", and since you don't really need this property to be writable, you can create a setter method that raises `NotImplemented` instead:

```
@__dict__.setter
def __dict__(self, value):
    raise NotImplemented
```

Demo: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=6f4749d404629ad87618784f570b9980

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark next to the answer if you find it to be correct.

Comment: It's just an exercise